# PrestoDB Cluster on Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, presto, google-cloud-run

I am trying to deploy prestoDB cluster on a serverless GCP Cloud Run. My understanding is that, since prestoDB uses REST API to communicate,

*[Coordinators communicate with workers and clients using a REST API](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/overview/concepts.html)*

it is possible to use Cloud Run since it's synchronous communication uses HTTP(S). The strategy was to use VPC Connector to connect each Cloud Run services (in which case is the prestoDB node) by setting them durring re/deployment while also setting them up in the same region. The (Cloud Run) access is also set to `allUsers` with the role of `run.invoker`.

[Cloud Run to Cloud Run Networking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrxEh.png)

Here's the deployment command,

```
// coordinator
gcloud run deploy presto-coordinator \
    --image $PRIVATE_PRESTODB_COORDINATOR_IMAGE \
    --memory=2Gi \
    --port=8080 \
    --vpc-connector=$VPC_ACCESS_CONNECTOR \
    --vpc-egress="all-traffic" \
    --region=$REGION_X

// worker

gcloud run deploy presto-worker \
    --image $PRIVATE_PRESTODB_WORKER_IMAGE \
    --memory=2Gi \
    --port=8080 \
    --ingress=internal-and-cloud-load-balancing\
    --vpc-connector=$VPC_ACCESS_CONNECTOR \
    --vpc-egress="all-traffic" \
    --region=$REGION_X
```

And here's the `config.properties` of the prestoDB nodes.

```
// coordinator

coordinator=true
node-scheduler.include-coordinator=true
http-server.http.port=$PORT
query.max-memory=5GB
query.max-memory-per-node=1GB
query.max-total-memory-per-node=2GB
discovery-server.enabled=true
discovery.uri=$CLOUD_RUN_COORDINATOR_URL:$PORT

// worker

coordinator=false
http-server.http.port=$PORT
query.max-memory=5GB
query.max-memory-per-node=1GB
query.max-total-memory-per-node=2GB
discovery.uri=$CLOUD_RUN_COORDINATOR_URL:$PORT
```

It successfully starts the coordinator service and the Cloud Run URL is able tho show the prestoDB ui, but does not detect the worker node(only it self aka the coordinator node). When trying the query i got,

```
Encountered too many errors talking to a worker node. The node may have crashed or be under too much load. This is probably a transient issue, so please retry your query in a few minutes.
```

Am I missing something or is it basically impossible to do so in Cloud Run?

Comment: Which port are you setting in `discovery.uri=$CLOUD_RUN_COORDINATOR_URL:$PORT`

Comment: @Puteri , I set the port to `8080` on both worker and coordinator.

Comment: Maybe that's the issue. When a service is published in Cloud Run the port exposed is 443 (and 80 but is redirected to port 443). The port you specify for the container when deploying is only to connect to the container but it’s not exposed.

Comment: @Puteri, but isn't that the purpose of the `--port` arguments when deploying? The request will be passed to the container port, which mentioned during re/deployment (cmiiw).

Comment: Nope. The `--port` is only the port where the Cloud Run Frontend will redirect the requests to the container but what is actually listening for connections is the CR FrontEnd (Port 443, 80). I'd suggest to check the documentation. https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract#port

Comment: @Puteri, thank you for the reference! May I ask, in the there it is mentioned that the container listen on `0.0.0.0` on port which request are sent.  So, does that mean, from the CRFE (443/80), the request are redirected to the `--port` of the CRFE, where container listen? Or from the CRFE (443/80) then `--port` of the container?

Comment: From the CRFE (443/80) then to the PORT of the container. Another way to see this is that the CRFE is a proxy in front of your container.

Comment: @Puteri, thanks for the clarification & replies, I've tried to adjust the `--port` and the `http-server.http.port` and `discovery.uri` as mentioned in https://prestodb.io/presto-admin/docs/current/installation/presto-port-configuration.html but sadly nothing work. Gonna keep it at that for now.